# Google Maps Javascript API V3 how to Placemark show name only

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

As a Title, I want show Placemark with Name field.
Basically, google map show Placemark with blue balloons.
but i don't wanna see this blue ballons. Just show Name only like google earth.
is it possible with google maps javascript api?

=============KML===============

```
<Folder>
   <name>Point Features</name>
   <description>Point Features</description>
   <Placemark>
     <description><![CDATA[LABEL<BR><BR><B>ELEVATION</B> = -2147483648.0000000]]></description>
     <name>lnd_a</name>
     <Point>
       <coordinates>126.3680042851,34.7669071990,-2147483648.000</coordinates>
     </Point>
   </Placemark>
   <!-- MY KML FILE HAS MORE LINE -->
</Folder>
```

=============Script Source===============

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.7958078334,126.4441270970);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://MYSITES/kml/101.kml');
    ctaLayer.setMap(map);
  }
```

[image: Google Maps in Chrome Web]
In Chrome Google Map Placemark shown with blue ballons.

[image: Google Earth Placemark]
In Google Earth Placemark shown with just name.

These screenshot base on same KML file.

How to show only name with Google Maps in Browser??

Comment: What does your existing code look like?  Default Google Maps API Markers ("balloons") are red with a dot, are you using KmlLayer to display KML on your map?  Default Markers there are blue.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I don't wanna see the blue ballons in google map. Just show name only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used it, but there is a library to show labels on a marker.  If you used a transparent marker with a label you may get the desired outcome.

[MarkerWithLabel](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/docs/reference.html)

If that doesn't work, I used to create custom labels for markers using an OverlayView.

[Create marker with custom labels in Google Maps API v3](http://www.tdmarketing.co.nz/blog/2011/03/09/create-marker-with-custom-labels-in-google-maps-api-v3/)

This would be an alternative to using KML Layers I guess.

Answer (score 1):

There is no implemented method to show anything else than an image there.

So 1 option could be: use the iconStyle to put there the  name(an image that contains the name, this may be created by a serverside script that accepts parameters, so they don't need to be static).

Another option(using the Maps-JS-API): Instead of showing the KML-layer, parse the layer on your own and create custom overlays with the names.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I already search in Google Maps Javascript Reference Page [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) but i cannot find any clue. :(