# Display marker on google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am developing a shop finding application For this, I want to display a particular type of shop (eg.Textile) 500m near to my position. I have the lat and Lon of the shops. Also GPS in the device will give me the current position. The only thing I want to know is, how to display the marker with address on google map.

There are many examples available for showing markers on map. But no info I can find for displaying markers 500m near to my position.

Answer (score 1):

Use : http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Marker-js.html --> open layer
[Google Maps Javascript API V3 how to Placemark show name only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330211/google-maps-javascript-api-v3-how-to-placemark-show-name-only) --> google map

Comment: My problem is not related to adding marker to google map. I want to mark places 500m near to me. The data can bet get from a web service.

Answer (score 1):

```
 function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}
```

It is simple marker example

Comment: here is full document for different types of markers:    https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple